# In what cases we shouldn't use Dependency Injection?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I read Effective Java and in item 5 I've been told to prefer dependency injection to hardwiring resources. 
 But immediately in the next item there's an example that violates it.

```
public class RomanNumerals {
    private static final Pattern ROMAN = Pattern.compile(
        "^(?=.)M*(C[MD]|D?C{0,3})"
            + "(X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})$");

    static boolean isRomanNumeral(String s) {
        return ROMAN.matcher(s).matches();
    }
}
```

Isn't `RomanNumerals` class depends on `Pattern` class? 
Why shouldn't we inject it?

Comment: I think this would be easier for you to understand, once you grasped the difference between instance and static members

Comment: `Pattern` respectively its instance `ROMAN` is not a resource but an algorithm (such that is has no state). What Effective Java means is that you should not hardwire a resource e.g. a database connection, a printer, a E-Mail server etc. but rather inject them.

Comment: @Stultuske I know the difference. In item 5 it is said that using static member for it is also wrong, because it is "inflexible & untestable".

Comment: How often does Roman numerals change? There are always exceptions to rules.

Comment: @bitterstudent compile is a static method. Do you need to have an (autowired) instance of Pattern to call it? isRomanNumeral is also static. Do you need an (autowired) instance of RomanNumerals to call it?